# ¿Porque cuando hago un commit no se actualiza la tabla de contribuciones de mi GitHub?

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-commit, repositorio

[image: text-image]

Durante un periodo de tiempo he estado haciendo commits a un repositorio, pero en la tabla de contribuciones de GitHub aparece como si no hubiera tenido actividad alguna.

A alguien mas le a pasado y como se puede solucionar? gracias.

Comment: ¿Hiciste los commits en un repositorio público o privado? Porque los commits que se hacen en repositorios privados solo son visibles como actividad en la tabla para los autores del repositorio.

Comment: Se puede configurar para que las contribuciones en repositorios privados aparezcan ahí

Comment: Es verdad. Por defecto no se puede, pero hay una manera de hacerlo como se explica [aquí](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/publicizing-or-hiding-your-private-contributions-on-your-profile).

Comment: No sé si sea el caso, pero según como esté configurado, github muestra como actividad sólo los commits que llegan a la rama principal (master o main).

Answer (score 0):

Asumo que estás acometiendo en un repositorio y **empujando** a github, cierto? O sea, si estás acometiendo en un repositorio *local* y no empujas a github, no hay manera de que github se entere. Habiendo descartado esa posibilidad, la otra posibilidad es que los commits que estás haciendo no estén quedando con el usuario que github conoce para tu usuario (ese match se hace a través de la dirección del correo del **commit author**, si no me equivoco).